# NelmioApiDoc model definition / how to ignore getter or alias to existing property with other name?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-php, nelmioapidocbundle

Can we overwride model accessor property name or ignore it?

Here my `User::getUsername` function which is an getter for email property (I need this function named like that to implement interface):

```
class User extends AbstractDocument implements AdvancedUserInterface, EquatableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     * @SWG\Property(
     *     description="The email of the user",
     *     example="example@company.com"
     * )
     */
    private $email;

    //...

    /**
     * Returns the username used to authenticate the user.
     * @return string The user email
     * @SWG\Property(property="email")
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

And the generated doc is still showing both:

```
{
  "User": {
    "properties":{
      "email":{  
        "description":"The email of the user",
        "example":"example@company.com",
        "type":"string"
      },
      "username":{  
        "type":"string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can you help me with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NelmioApiDoc respects the Ignore attribute, so you can hide the method/field like this:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Ignore;

/**
 * @Ignore
 */
public function getUsername()

// or

#[Ignore]
public function getUsername()
```